# Simulate image "overlay" with CSS

Tags: html, css, background

Basically I'm trying to simulate Photoshop's image overlay thing using images and CSS for a menu.

There are 2 versions of the menu background image: one is the normal state (pink), and one the active state (blue). The entire menu is wrapped in a DIV with the normal (pink) image as background.

How can I make it so each active menu link uses the corresponding slice of the blue image?

Like this:

[image]

[**My code so far**](http://jsfiddle.net/JzTWq/1/)

Do you think this is possible with CSS?

Comment: Can you provide your current code?

Comment: I wouldn't use an image at all. This is completely feasible with CSS exclusively.

Comment: I was thinking of putting a span element with the background inside the links with 100% width relative to the entire menu, and using z-index somehow to achieve this...

Comment: I would make this little more flexible. The thing that is being a big hindrance is the reaaally long inconsistant height of the highlight. You would pretty much have to replicate each position again with the hover.. I would make the middle parts highlight consistant height till the very end. http://img192.imageshack.us/img192/2115/qztun.jpg it changes the menu image a little but its a sacrifice i would make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to support older browsers and can't use css3, there is a number of ways to do this. One of them:
You can cut out the blue image of the entire thing (you can actually make it wider)

then

```
li.active {
    background: url('path/to/yourImage.png') no-repeat -50px 0;
    /* 50px or however wide that rounded tip is */
}

li.active.first {
    background-position: left top;
}

li.active.last {
    background-position: right top;
}
/* you'll need to add 'active', 'first' and 'last' classes accordingly. */
```

Answer (score 3):

CSS Only solution for modern browsers:

```
ul {
    background-color:#ff00ff;
    background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(50% 50%, ellipse closest-side, #ffffff 0%,#ff00ff 110%);
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 50%, ellipse closest-side, #ffffff 0%,#ff00ff 110%);  
    background-image: -o-radial-gradient(50% 50%, ellipse closest-side, #ffffff 0%,#ff00ff 110%);
    background-image: -ms-radial-gradient(50% 50%, ellipse closest-side, #ffffff 0%,#ff00ff 110%);
    background-image: radial-gradient(50% 50%, ellipse closest-side, #ffffff 0%,#ff00ff 110%);
    height:50px;
    width:400px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-radius:25px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

li {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
}

li:hover {
    background-color:rgba(0,0,255,0.2);
}
```

Click to see a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/ZLg4B/

Comment: +1 Excellent work! Although I wouldn't want to visit the site with that navbar on it; _personally_ I think it's a bit too harsh, but I'm seeing it out of context of course. No disrespect @OP.

Comment: it won't look like this in reality, this just the idea :) Anyway the menu is too complex to reproduce with just CSS. I need the images...

Comment: I think to give any more help, we would need an example of the image complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Are you ever going to have links at the rounded parts? If not, you could just take a pixel-wide slice of the blue image and set that to the `:hover` state background with `repeat-x`.

There are definitely other ways to do this but this is the most straightforward IMHO.

---

Edit: After seeing your fiddle, perhaps this isn't the case. I would consider using JavaScript to calculate appropriate x-offsets for each link, and using a slice of the overlay image in that way. Or you could just make the first link a "special case" and use a generic different-color background for the rest of the links.